# JSF Flow. End current flow and start a new one

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, omnifaces, flow-scope

I have a web application where a user can start a search from almost all pages of the application.

Every time a user searches I would like to start a new flow, so basically I have:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{myBean.startNewSearch}" .../>

public void startNewSearch(){
    //Some validations and pre-conditions
    Faces.navigate("exitSearchFlow");
    //Perform search
    return "startSearchFlow";
}
```

I can see with the loggers that the flow is started and the flow is finished but jfwid never changes (I'm using faces-redirect=true, the form parameter does not change either).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You must define the sub flows inside your main flow.
Define a Flow for search, and inside your search-flow define the other flows, using the flow-call. ex:

```
 <flow-definition id="searchFlow">
        <flow-call id="subFlowA">
        <flow-reference>
            <flow-id>subFlowA-File-ID</flow-id>
        </flow-reference>
        </flow-call>
        <flow-call id="subFlowB">
        </flow-call>
 </flow-definition>
```

You can pass parameters to the sub flow. To call the sub flows use the Id of the Flow-Call. Ex:

```
<h:commandButton value="Call Flow A" action="subFlowA"/>
```

You can find details in the following link:

[JSF Flows](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-configure003.htm)